# space dependent compilation before \end{name} environment

Tags: environments, comments

I discovered a curious phenomenon today... Depending on the beginning of line n°11 of the following latex code, I have a problem compilation or not!

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{comment}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\excludecomment{test}

\begin{document}
    \begin{test}
        \lipsum[1][1]
    \end{test}
\end{document}
```

Here, line 11 begins with a tabulation and compilation is OK. There is also no problem if the line begins directly by `\end{test}`.
Nevertheless, if line 11 begins with two spaces, I got the following compilation error:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
<inserted text>
\par
<*> test.tex
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
! Emergency stop.
<*> test.tex
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
639 strings out of 478994
13626 string characters out of 5858184
474122 words of memory out of 5000000
18189 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
403430 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
71i,0n,75p,182b,46s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Is someone could explain the phenomena? Is this related with the implementation of comment package?

Comment: In order to avoid strange effects, all verbatim-like environments (and `comment` defined ones are such) should not be indented.

Comment: as the documentation says "The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No starting spaces, nothing after it."

Comment: Thank you for your answer